# How do I implement an "include" in Java Class Association

Tags: java, uml

I understand what inherit does in Java Class Associations which is the extend feature. But I don't know what include means, I've researched and can only find implements but not sure if that's what includes means.

Here is the UML design.

StudentRecord (1) ---- includes ---- (1) Student 
     FullTimeStudent (1) ---- inherits ----> (1) Student

Comment: I think you're asking for a "has-a" relationship, or *composition*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the difference, technically:

First one: StudentRecord (1) ---- includes ---- (1) Student
This means StudentRecord contains a member variable of type Student, something like

```
public class StudentRecord {
    private Student student;
    // and other member variables and functions
}
```

Second: FullTimeStudent (1) ---- inherits ----> (1) Student
This means that FullTimeStudent is a Student. like:

```
public class FullTimeStudent extends Student {
    // override stuff, add new members
}
```

See the difference? One says **"contains"**, while the other **"is a"**.
i.e. you can write something like:

```
Student s = new FullTimeStudent();
```

and

```
StudentRecord sr = new StudentRecord(student);
// given you have such a constructor, or:
studentRecord.setStudent(s);
```